# how to upload a file from a remote server to s3 in java?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, file-upload, inputstream

The file is basically in a remote server. Example, using http://example.com/example.pdf. I need to stream this file to s3 and save it.

```
URL url = new URL(" http://example.com/example.pdf");
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
metadata.setContentType("application/pdf");
metadata.setContentLength(in.available());
PutObjectRequest objectRequest = new PutObjectRequest("bucket","key",in,metadata);
PutObjectResult result = s3AwsClient.putObject(objectRequest);
```

Is it possible without saving it to the server i am running this code?

Comment: You are supposed to set the content length from the *actual header of your URL connection*. Not `available()` which has nothing to do with the content length.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Thank you for the comment, I am now adding the content-length from the remote server file. Now I am getting an exception (More data read than expected ) with the content-length mismatch. Precisely 32bytes additional than actual byte of the file. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: What do you mean, from the remote server file? You are supposed to take the content-length header from your URL-connection. As in `connection.getContentLengthLong()`.